# how to fix "error in ssl handshake" in cpprestsdk?

Tags: c++, openssl, casablanca

I'm using cpprestsdk "Casablanca" master branch with https url, it's working on both windows and osx but when i run it on linux i received "Error is ssl handshake"

```
C++ exception with description "Error in SSL handshake" thrown in the test body.
```

i tried to open this url using firefox it worked.

when i used it with http url it worked properly 
i checked the code i found this message in one file named "http_client_asio.cpp"

```
void write_request()
    {
        // Only perform handshake if a TLS connection and not being reused.
        if (m_connection->is_ssl() && !m_connection->is_reused())
        {
            const auto weakCtx = std::weak_ptr<asio_context>(shared_from_this());
            m_connection->async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                                          m_http_client->client_config(),
                                          m_http_client->base_uri().host(),
                                          boost::bind(&asio_context::handle_handshake, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error),

                                          // Use a weak_ptr since the verify_callback is stored until the connection is destroyed.
                                          // This avoids creating a circular reference since we pool connection objects.
                                          [weakCtx](bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context &verify_context)
                                          {
                                              auto this_request = weakCtx.lock();
                                              if(this_request)
                                              {
                                                  return this_request->handle_cert_verification(preverified, verify_context);
                                              }
                                              return false;
                                          });
        }
        else
        {
            m_connection->async_write(m_body_buf, boost::bind(&asio_context::handle_write_headers, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }

    void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            m_connection->async_write(m_body_buf, boost::bind(&asio_context::handle_write_headers, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            report_error("Error in SSL handshake", ec, httpclient_errorcode_context::handshake);
        }
    }
```

in the client side i craeted http client like this

```
http_client client(U("https://www.bing.com/"));
```

how can i fix this error ?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264313/ssl-certificates-and-boost-asio).

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint and add more information about the `ec` object that causes the message? Also, have you tried other sites? If you can reproduce the issue with an http site, you can try using wireshark to inspect the network communications.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem when trying to connect to an https URL.

First, if you don't need to connect to https, you could just replace your url to a http one.

Another solution is to set your http_client_config credentials validation to false. Something like this:

```
    http_client_config config;
    config.set_validate_certificates(false);
```

But if you need to make a https connections with security included, you must include your local certificate file (generally a CRT, or DEM file) and set it as a callback in your http_client config:

```
    http_client_config config;
    config.set_ssl_context_callback([]((boost::asio::ssl::context &ctx) {
        ctx.load_verify_file("PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE_FILE");
    });
```

You could see more about these functions here:

https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1client_1_1http__client__config.html