# Where does cpprestsdk look for certificates on macOS/Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, cpprest-sdk

Where does `cpprestsdk` look for certificates on macOS/Linux?

Currently, I get an TLS handshake error, despite valid root certificates being present in the system store.

Curl makes use of `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`. Does the same apply to `cpprestsdk`, and if so, where can I look it up for reference?

Comment: it just uses `boost::asio`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264313/ssl-certificates-and-boost-asio